# Creating chess board and generating number in each row increaced by 1 PHP?

Tags: php

[image: i want to display like the picture below]

I have generated a chessboard using nested for loop but I can't figure out to display the number on its

My Code

```
<?php
    $cellNum=2;
      $rowNum=1;
      $color=['#FFFFFF','#000000'];
      $color1='#FFFFFF';
      $color2='#000000';

    for($row=1;$row<=6;$row++){
        echo "<tr>";
        for($col=1;$col<=6;$col++) {
            $total=$row+$col;
            $i=1;
            if($total%2==0) {
                echo "<td height=50px width=50px bgcolor=#FFFFFF align='center'></td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td height=50px width=50px bgcolor=#000000 style='color:white; text-align:center;'></td>";
            }
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Just add a separate counter before the first loop, initialize it with a value of 1 and then increment it by one on each cell you generate. After generating each cell, print the counter's current value inside the cell

Comment: Oh and for what it's worth... Chess boards are 8x8, not 6x6 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply your row and column.

```
for($row=1;$row<=6;$row++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($col=1;$col<=6;$col++) {
        $total=$row+$col;
        $i=1;
        if($total%2==0) {
            echo "<td height=50px width=50px bgcolor=#FFFFFF align='center'>".$row*$col."</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td height=50px width=50px bgcolor=#000000 style='color:white; text-align:center;'>".$row*$col."</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to display the numbers between the  tags:

```
$val = $row*$col;
if($total%2==0) {
    echo "<td height=50px width=50px bgcolor=#FFFFFF align='center'>$val</td>";
} else {
    echo "<td height=50px width=50px bgcolor=#000000 style='color:white; text-align:center;'>$val</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were so close I am almost embaraced to answer the question

```
<?php
    $cellNum=2;
    $rowNum=1;
    $color=['#FFFFFF','#000000'];
    $color1='#FFFFFF';
    $color2='#000000';
    
    echo '<table border="1">';
    for($row=1;$row<=6;$row++){
        echo "<tr>";
        for($col=1;$col<=6;$col++) {
            
            $total=$row*$col;
            
            if(($row+$col) % 2 == 0) {
                echo "<td height=50px width=50px bgcolor=#FFFFFF align='center'>$total</td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td height=50px width=50px bgcolor=#000000 style='color:white; text-align:center;'>$total</td>";
            }
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Giving

[image]